# Visual Studio Community 2015 problems after Update 1 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have run, "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 1 RC", to try to solve some of my problems with the RTM version of VS.
And indeed, I now have a working XAML WPF designer.
But the Update 1 has introduced different problems and not solved some.
This is on a Windows 10 Laptop (upgraded from Windows 8.1).

1. I still get this error:

Android SDK Setup (API Level 23) : The following package(s) were not downloaded: build-tools-23.0.1 android-23. Please check your internet connection and try again.

There is nothing wrong with my cable internet connection, the Firewall is off and the AntiVirus uninstalled (temporarily).

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

2. After installing Update 1 RC, I have VS components in multiple Languages, such as:-
   Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 目標套件 (繁體中文)
   Microsoft 도움말 뷰어 2.2 언어 팩 - 한국어
   Microsoft ヘルプ ビューアー 2.2 言語パック - 日本語
   Языковой пакет средства просмотра справки (Майкрософт) 2.2 — RUS

Is this an issue others have had with Update 1 RC?
I guess I can just remove the non-english versions - yes?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you're behind a proxy?

In such a case, open the Android SDK, go to Tools menu and hit the Options. Then define your proxy settings. Be careful, server and port are different fields there and should be filled appropriately.

Comment: I encountered exactly this problem and your tip saved my day.